# ipcRenderer EventEmitter not working with capacitor and electron/vue

Tags: node.js, electron, capacitor

I am trying to develop a project that runs on electron and capacitor android at the same time. I get this error when I run my electron app. It relates to the preload script. This script allows me to do IPC between the main thread and the vue thread. After installing capacitor none of my electron IPC works.

This is the error:

```
    Uncaught Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
        at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (VM115 preloadx.js:49:57)
        at EventEmitter.emit (VM14 node:events:390:28)
        at Object.onMessage (VM113 renderer_init:69:746)
```

This is the renderer script. It is in the public folder. Node puts it into the 'out' folder, which is where it is found during execution.

```
    const {
        contextBridge,
        ipcRenderer, 
    } = require("electron");

     let validChannels = [
                "api",
                "ascii",
                // some channels here ...
                "py-neo",
            ];



    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
        "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
                    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args)); // <-- error on this line!!
            }
        },
        sendSync: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.sendSync(channel, data);
            }
        },

    }
    );
```

Here is some code from the main thread js file.

```
    function createWindow() {
      console.log("createWindow", __dirname);
      mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
          //sandbox: true,
          contextIsolation: true, 
          enableRemoteModule: true, 
          nodeIntegration: true,  
          nodeIntegrationInWorker: true, 
          preload: path.join(__dirname, "out", "preload.js"), // use a preload script
        },
      });
```

I am using electron 18.1.0 and node 16.15.1. I would like the IPC to work when I launch on the desktop. It does not need to work when I launch in Android studio. below is a segment from my package.json file.

```
  "scripts": {
"start": "vue-cli-service build && electron --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer .  ",
 "dist": "electron-builder",
 "build": "vue-cli-service build",
 "android": "npx cap sync android"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like the following to remove the error message.

```
  contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
      "api", {
      send: (channel, data) => {
          // whitelist channels
          if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
              ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
          }
      },
      receive: (channel, func) => {
          if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
              // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
              ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => {
                console.log(channel , ...args);
                try {
                  func(...args);

                }
                catch {
                  console.log(...args);
                }
                //func(...args)
              });
          }
      },
      sendSync: (channel, data) => {
          // whitelist channels
          if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
              return ipcRenderer.sendSync(channel, data);
          }
      },

  }
  );
```